# CKEditor5 How to prevent shirink textarea in Blazor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, blazor, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor5 classic (37.1.0) in Blazor and creation js code below.

But when I click the editor area, textarea is shirinked. How to prevent textarea is shirinked? Or, is there 'min-height' option in CKEditor5?

```
function loadEditor() {
    ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
        .then(editor => {
            editor.ui.view.editable.element.style.height = '400px';
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

[image]

razor page is here..

```
    <MudPaper Elevation="0" Class="mt-5">
        <div id="editor">
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </MudPaper>
```

Comment: try this `#editor .ck-editor__editable { min-height: 400px; }`

Comment: I suggest you could try this `editor.ui.view.editable.element.style.minHeight = '400px';`

Comment: @RohadBokhar already tried it. It is not worked

Comment: @BrandoZhang Ok, I'd try this.

Comment: @BrandoZhang Unfortunatly, It didn't work...

Comment: can you try to override on focus css?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem that because of CSS Isolation. I append the flowing css code in razor page directly and it works. But I don't know why css isolation is not worked..

Thanks Rohad.

```
<style>
    .ck-editor__editable{
        min-height:400px;
    }
</style>
```